# SQL Server queries take forever to enumerate the dataset?

Tags: sql-server, vmware-workstation, sql-server-2005, osql

I've got an interesting sounding problem with SQL queries run from a particular machine.
This machine is a VM running Windows Server 2003, and it has SQL Server Express 2005 on it.

The VM was migrated from a VMWare Player image into a proper VMWare Workstation setup. It ran fine when it was running under the Player only (on different physical hardware.)

From this machine, if I run osql and connect to its own SQLEXPRESS instance, queries run horribly slowly (10 minutes to return and print 1000 rows from a select statement.)
If I run osql and connect to another database server, queries run at a similar speed.

From this machine, if I use SSMS to run a query it performs fine! The same table is open for editing in less than a second.
I ran osql on another machine, and connected to the VM with this issue. Querying the exact same test as before runs very quickly, too.

The main reason this is an issue is because our webapps on this VM run as slowly as osql does, instead of the more normal speed exhibited by SSMS. These webapps use v2.0.50727 of the standard System.Data dll for their queries and connections.

Has anyone seen these symptoms before, and/or knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually appeared to have been an issue with having Tracing turned on in the ODBC data sources control panel.

To check this setting:

Start -> Settings -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Data Sources (ODBC) 
Select the Tracing tab.
Make sure Tracing is turned off.